# How to hide/show a column in a basic column graph of highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to show/hide a column (with all the associated points) in a graph of highcharts.

For instance, consider following graph: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/).

I want the user to be able to click on the "Sep" column, hide it, rescale the axis accordingly (x and y axis).

Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in javascript/jquery. So I was wondering if it is possible to do that, and how.

Thanks for your help!

Here is the code of the fiddle:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: I made a solution. Took me an hour and then jsfiddle crashed for me :'( . Anyway take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-click-to-add/ and here http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/whFvA/2/ to get started. Use setCategories and setData. There are also some similar threads here at stackoverflow and also highcharts forum (eg http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16169)

Comment: Oh, my old good examples :) Nice @daker! To make them work, change URL  for Highcharts library. Fixed ones: http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/4/ and http://jsfiddle.net/5m9JW/381/

Comment: @daker and Pawel thanks for your answers. It's exactly what I was looking for! I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution from Daker, with the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/4/).

html

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<button id="b4">Hide third category</button>
<button id="b5">Show third category</button>
```

javascript

```
var point = {
x: null,
y: null
};

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
},

series: [{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'third',
    data: [95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1],
}]
});
$('#b4').click(function () {
var no = 2; //third element
// removed march, hoping we'd only show 11 months...
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'], false);
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
    if (i < no) {
        data.push([chart.series[0].data[i].x, chart.series[0].data[i].y]);
    } else if (i === no) {
        point.x = chart.series[0].data[i].x;
        point.y = chart.series[0].data[i].y;
    } else if (i > no) {
        data.push([chart.series[0].data[i].x - 1, chart.series[0].data[i].y]);
    }
}
chart.series[0].setData(data);
});

$('#b5').click(function () {
var no = 2; //third element
var data = [];
for (i = 0; i < chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
    if (i < no) {
        data.push([chart.series[0].data[i].x, chart.series[0].data[i].y]);
    } else if (i === no) {
        data.push([point.x, point.y]);
        data.push([chart.series[0].data[i].x + 1, chart.series[0].data[i].y]);
    } else if (i > no) {
        data.push([chart.series[0].data[i].x + 1, chart.series[0].data[i].y]);
    }
}
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']);
chart.series[0].setData(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with a grouped bar chart, you will need to create a custom function that will

1) remove the data series from the chart

2) rebuild the data series with the clicked data points removed

3) re-add the series to the chart

and,

4) you will need to build some form of external control mimicking a legend, so that the user still has something to click in order to re-show the removed data.  Otherwise, when you rescale the axis, you remove the label and the user can't get the data back.

It is not a trivial exercise, unfortunately.

the setData() function will handle 1 and 3:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29

**OTOH**, if you want to do this with a standard (non-grouped, non-stacked) bar chart, you can simply make each bar a separate data series, and the built in Legend functionality will handle everything for you.