# How can I hide and show a category in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I've been trying to make a dynamical way for the user to toggle the categories of a line highchart, I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts) that seemed to have what I was looking for, I added the code to my page, changed a few things.

The problem is that when I hide a category(years) it changes the number of the category to the position of the category in the highchart and when I show it displays the data for that category but also adds a new category...Here's my http://jsfiddle.net/antonioj1015/3pxbat0p/

```
$(function () {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Name',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: ',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['2009','2010','2011']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Porc (%)'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{ id: 'id09', name: '0-9', data: [0.29, 0.29, 0.26] }, 
            { id: 'id1019', name: '10-19', data: [0.96, 1.08, 0.87] }, 
            { id: 'id2029', name: '20-29', data: [2.55, 2.34, 1.68] }, 
            { id: 'id3039', name: '30-39', data: [5.37, 4.67, 4.04] }, 
            { id: 'id4049', name: '40-49', data: [14.60, 12.65, 11.52] }, 
            { id: 'id5059', name: '50-59', data: [27.02, 25.68, 25.00] }, 
            { id: 'id6069', name: '60-69', data: [26.16, 27.28, 28.48] }, 
            { id: 'id7079', name: '70-79', data: [16.99, 18.80, 20.33] }, 
            { id: 'id80omas', name: '80 o mas', data: [6.07, 7.21, 7.82] }]
});

    $("#chkbox_2009").on("click", function(e){
        var tmp_pl = $.trim($(this).data("val"));
        var cat_name = $(this).data("val");

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.push(cat_name);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.get("id09").addPoint(0.29);
                chart.get("id1019").addPoint(0.96);
                chart.get("id2029").addPoint(2.55);
                chart.get("id3039").addPoint(5.37);
                chart.get("id4049").addPoint(14.60);
                chart.get("id5059").addPoint(27.02);
                chart.get("id6069").addPoint(26.16);
                chart.get("id7079").addPoint(16.99);
                chart.get("id80omas").addPoint(6.07);
                chart.redraw();

        } else {
            var cat;
            var data_series = [];
            $.each(chart.series, function(sKey, sVal){
                var j = sVal.data.length - 1;
                var isRemoved = false;
                var dt;
                while(!isRemoved && j >= 0) {
                    var dVal = sVal.data[j];
                    if (dVal.category === cat_name) {
                        dVal.remove();
                        sVal.xIncrement --;
                        isRemoved = true;
                    }
                    j--;
                }

                $.each(sVal.data, function(k,v){
                    v.update({
                        x: k
                    });
                });
            });

            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.splice( $.inArray(cat_name, categories), 1 );
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.redraw();
        }
    });
    $("#chkbox_2010").on("click", function(e){
        var tmp_pl = $.trim($(this).data("val"));
        var cat_name = $(this).data("val");

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.push(cat_name);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.get("id09").addPoint(0.29);
                chart.get("id1019").addPoint(1.08);
                chart.get("id2029").addPoint(2.34);
                chart.get("id3039").addPoint(4.67);
                chart.get("id4049").addPoint(12.65);
                chart.get("id5059").addPoint(25.68);
                chart.get("id6069").addPoint(27.28);
                chart.get("id7079").addPoint(18.80);
                chart.get("id80omas").addPoint(7.21);
                chart.redraw();

        } else {
            var cat;
            var data_series = [];
            $.each(chart.series, function(sKey, sVal){
                var j = sVal.data.length - 1;
                var isRemoved = false;
                var dt;
                while(!isRemoved && j >= 0) {
                    var dVal = sVal.data[j];
                    if (dVal.category === cat_name) {
                        dVal.remove();
                        sVal.xIncrement --;
                        isRemoved = true;
                    }
                    j--;
                }

                $.each(sVal.data, function(k,v){
                    v.update({
                        x: k
                    });
                });
            });

            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.splice( $.inArray(cat_name, categories), 1 );
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.redraw();
        }
    });
    $("#chkbox_2011").on("click", function(e){
        var tmp_pl = $.trim($(this).data("val"));
        var cat_name = $(this).data("val");

        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.push(cat_name);
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.get("id09").addPoint(0.26);
                chart.get("id1019").addPoint(0.87);
                chart.get("id2029").addPoint(1.68);
                chart.get("id3039").addPoint(4.04);
                chart.get("id4049").addPoint(11.52);
                chart.get("id5059").addPoint(25.00);
                chart.get("id6069").addPoint(28.48);
                chart.get("id7079").addPoint(20.33);
                chart.get("id80omas").addPoint(7.82);
                chart.redraw();

        } else {
            var cat;
            var data_series = [];
            $.each(chart.series, function(sKey, sVal){
                var j = sVal.data.length - 1;
                var isRemoved = false;
                var dt;
                while(!isRemoved && j >= 0) {
                    var dVal = sVal.data[j];
                    if (dVal.category === cat_name) {
                        dVal.remove();
                        sVal.xIncrement --;
                        isRemoved = true;
                    }
                    j--;
                }

                $.each(sVal.data, function(k,v){
                    v.update({
                        x: k
                    });
                });
            });

            var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories;
            categories.splice( $.inArray(cat_name, categories), 1 );
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
            chart.redraw();
        }
    });});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of setting categories etc, you can catch checkbox event and show/hide the particual SVG element.

```
 var $check,
        val;

    $('input[name="cat"]').click(function(){
        $check = $(this);
        val = $check.val();

        $.each(chart.xAxis[0].ticks, function(i, tick){
            if(tick.label && tick.label.textStr == val){
                $check.is(':checked') ? tick.label.show() : tick.label.hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e33bh48x/2/

Comment: Yes but I need all of the column to not be displayed, the code hides the label on the xAxis but the values keep showing.

Comment: Have you seen this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts