# How to show/hide categories with checkbox using highcharts?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I want show/hide some categories in highcharts using checkbox, can you help me? This is my code so far:

```
var categories = chart.categories[0];
if(categories.graphic.visibility == 'hidden'){
    categories.graphic.show();
} else {
    categories.graphic.hide();
}
```

Comment: This has an answer on SO already , refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745540/how-can-i-hide-and-show-a-category-in-highcharts  

for the answer

Comment: i want show,hide categories, this is only show and hide label

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/4/ but with checkbox

Comment: Then just replace the buttons with checkboxes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty common question in a variety of forms, and with a variety of solutions.

I have created a demo to do this in a way that is dynamically built upon a pre-processed category array and series object.

- It uses the array of categories to build a list of `checkboxes` for each.
- On `click`, it looks through the list to determine which boxes are checked.
- Then it loops through the predefined `series` object, and for each series loops through the data and builds a new array containing only the points for which the boxes are checked.
- Uses `setData` on each series to update the points/categories displayed.
- relies on each data point having the `name` attribute specified, and each series having an `id` specified.

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/nLcu3f7h/

There are a number of other things going on in the fiddle - it dynamically creates box plots out of randomly generated data, and dynamically builds a category array - these are unimportant to the purpose.  They result in what is mentioned above: a categories array, which is used to a) build the checkboxes, and b) populate the `name` for each data point, and a series object to loop through to build the chart series.

**{{ edit ---------------**

*A slimmer version, using 3 column series:*

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/wqwawuLq/

**--------------- /edit }}**

The functions that matter are:

- `buildCheckboxes()`
- `rebuildData()`
- The `$(document).on('click', '#check-boxes input'...` listener

This requires proper pre-processing of your data, but should be able to work with any number and type of series.

Comment: Showing the categories doesn't work. I've edited your code and everything seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0k4m5d2q/
I used different approach for manipulating the data. 

Related post: https://forum.highcharts.com/post136313.html

Comment: @Kamil yeah, I noticed that wasn't working anymore, but haven't had a chance to look at why (the answer is 2 years old, afterall though :) ). Update looks good.