# linkedTo with multiple ID in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have a 3x3 matrix of data series which I am plotting via Highcharts

```
        Cat1   |    Cat2     |   Cat3

 Type1  [...]      [...]         [...]

 Type2  [...]      [...]         [...]

 Type3  [...]      [...]         [...]
```

So I am plotting 9 seires `[...]` and I want to have 6 legends in my highchart i.e. `(Cat1, Cat2, Cat3, Type1, Type2, Type3)`.

Clicking on `Cat1` Will hide all the series in the column `Cat1` and clicking on `Type1` will hide all the series in the row `Type1`.

Right now I am able to have this functionality with 3 legends either `(Cat1, Cat2, Cat3)` or `(Type1, Type2, Type3)` by using `linkedTo` and `id`, but how can I have all the six legends with this functionality?

Comment: Hi, I think that you can make custom legend in case of your chart. Then you can check if your series has name or type equal to clicked legend item and then show it or hide. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lqgzy9e/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński thats perfect!.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński there is one issue I am seeing, click on 1 and than on 2 and than on area the result should be line and column of series 3 but your solution is resulting in line and column of series 3 and along with area of 1 and 2.

Comment: Hi, of course, it all depends on how you would like your chart to look and what is the functionallity you would like to achieve. I think that you want something similar to this option, am I right? http://jsfiddle.net/5Lqgzy9e/3/

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind for me on how to accomplish this is related to this question:

- [How to show/hide categories with checkbox using highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776861/how-to-show-hide-categories-with-checkbox-using-highcharts)

Which lead to this solution:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/wqwawuLq/

It uses check boxes to show/hide categories, rather than the legend. It could probably be adapted to work with a set of dummy series, and the `legendItemClick` event rather than check boxes.

I made a modified version here to work with having categories on both the x and y axes, which may suit your needs:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/jrxqpbmf/

Output example:

[image: screenshot]