# Filter categories in highcharts by using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, highcharts

I would like to filter the categories by using the checkboxes. For example, if the user checks Server - only Categories belonging to class Server should be visible and redraw the highchart.

[image: 1]

Like this:

[image: After]

And if the user checks all checkboxes, all categories should be visible.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcrgrbh/

Thanks in advance!

```
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart('container', {
chart: {
  type: 'columnrange',
  inverted: true,
  height: 100
},

title: {
  text: null
},

xAxis: {
  categories: [{"name":"Email","sys_class":"Business Service"},{"name":"Server","sys_class":"Server"}],

  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return this.value.name;

    },
    useHTML: true
  }
},
yAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 6,
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  labels: {
    formatter: function () {
      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %Y', this.value);
    }
  }
},

plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false,
    stacking: 'normal',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0.0,
    allowPointSelect: true,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      align: 'center',
      x: -10,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.series.name;
      }
    }
  }
},

tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    var categories = this.x.name,
    series_name = this.series.name,
    low = this.point.low,
    high = this.point.high,
    duration = high - low;
    return '<b>' +series_name + '</b><br/><b>'+ categories + ': </b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y',
    new Date(low)) + " - " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y',
    new Date(high)) + '<br/><b>Duration: </b>' + parseInt(duration / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)) + " years, " + new Date(duration).getUTCMonth() + " months, " + new Date(duration).getUTCDate() + " days";
  }
},

legend: {
  enabled: false
},

series: [{"color":"#f47700","data":[[],[1475539200000,1570147200000]],"name":"Concept"},{"color":"#f43701","data":[[1475625600000,1570233600000],[]],"name":"Planing"}]

});
});
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve something similar to this example? http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcrgrbh/1/ if yes, I will post it as an answer

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776861/how-to-show-hide-categories-with-checkbox-using-highcharts  and this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/wqwawuLq/

Comment: @Grzegorz yes, this is exactly what I need.

Comment: And whats about coulm range? http://jsfiddle.net/8b807xdj/2/

Comment: Thanks! Got it http://jsfiddle.net/8b807xdj/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to edit your togglePointsByClass method so you will not hide your series, but you will change extremes on your xAxis. In this case you can use Axis.update() method.

```
  function togglePointsByClass(className, shouldShow, chart) {
    var isChartDirty = false;
    if (shouldShow) {
      chart.xAxis[0].userOptions.categories.forEach(function(category, i) {
        if (category.class === className) {
          visibleArr.push(i);
        }
      });
    } else {
      chart.xAxis[0].userOptions.categories.forEach(function(category, i) {
        if (category.class === className && visibleArr.indexOf(i) > -1) {
          visibleArr.splice(visibleArr.indexOf(i), 1);
        }
      });
    }
    if (visibleArr.length) {
      chart.xAxis[0].update({
        min: Math.min.apply(null, visibleArr),
        max: Math.max.apply(null, visibleArr)
      })
    }
  }
```

Here you can see simple example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcrgrbh/1/

Comment: But for this case to update min, max of XAxis will not work: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqcrgrbh/2/

Comment: Yes, because you are want to hide part of series that is between different points. The solution in this case may be to use breaks: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks