# Highcharts column chart grouping

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an array of the following objects:

[image]

Now my goal is to create column chart that would look something like this:

[image]

And then the next object in my array.

I have been looking through the documentation and all I was able to find was something like this:

[Highcharts demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped/dark-unica)

The problem is the `data` value that you set in the series. if you insert an array it will be split across all categories. As far as I can see you cannot lock one data series to one category.

What can I try next?

My attempt:

I'm attempting within this fiddle:

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
        xAxis: {
            minPadding: 0.05,
            maxPadding: 0.05,
            categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
        },
        series: [{
                type: 'column',
            name: 'Apples',
            zoneAxis: 'x',
            data: [
                ['First', 29.9],
                ['Second', 71.5],
                ['Third', 106.4]
            ]
        },{
            type: 'column',
          name: 'oranges',
          data:[
            ['A', 20]
          ]
        }]
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yohrpjpt/)

Comment: It's easier to help with an fiddle of your actual code and example, rather than a somewhat related Highcharts demo. Short answer is yes, you are correct that it is not meant to work that way, but also yes, with some manipulation you should be able to get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to approach this, and the best option depends on how specific your needs are.

The first way that comes to mind, is to just manipulate how you structure your data and your categories.

**Example:**

```
   xAxis: {
      categories: ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3'],
      labels: { style: { fontWeight: 'bold' } }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Subset A',
            data: [{y: 10, name: '1A'}, {y: 5, name: '2A'}, {y: 7, name: '3A'}]
    }, {
      name: 'Subset B',
            data: [{y: 5, name: '1B'}, {y: 3, name: '2B'}, {y: 4, name: '3B'}]
    }]
```

So, assuming three groups, each with two points. You want the first category to show point **A** and **B** from **Group 1**, the second category to show point **A** and **B** from **Group 2**, etc.

**Fiddle:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hLfajxz9/

**Output:**

[image]

The main potential downside to this is that the legend will show/hide points A or B, and not Group 1, 2, or 3.

You can work around this by adding a function to show/hide categories, if that's an issue.

Check out the answer on this question here:

- [How to show/hide categories with checkbox using highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776861/how-to-show-hide-categories-with-checkbox-using-highcharts)

And the related fiddle here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/wqwawuLq/