# Highcharts column chart "re-draw"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Please consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmbw75mg/4/

As you can see, there are 3 `data` points. You are able to hide/show the series by clicking on the corresponding legend item. When you click on `dog` or `bird` the chart nicely reacts, and redraws; removing the x-axis label and only displaying 2 columns.

Why doesn't this happen when I click on `fish`? How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: Because these categories are "on the edge". In highcharts there is not build-in algorithm which slice a categories in middle. But you can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and adapt examples from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts) topic.

Comment: To clarify/elaborate on Sebastian's point, the two columns "on the edge", as he put it, affect the x Axis scaling - if they're not their, the axis is shorter (ie, if the first column goes away, the middle column is now the lowest x value). If the middle column is missing, the lowest and highest x axis point do not change, and so the axis is re-drawn, but it hasn't changed. The  series show/hide functionality does not by default remove the axis label - that happens via the axis rescaling functionality instead.