# Show/hide part of series in highcharts base on x-axis category

Tags: highcharts

I've a multi-series column highchart. I want to create a legend/button to hide part of chart. For ex: I want to hide/show from Aug to Oct in this following chart:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic

Is there a way to do that without split my series?

Thank you.

Comment: You can narrow/extend xAxis range by updating its min/max - http://jsfiddle.net/u855cvfv/ If you are looking for hiding middle part of the axis range then you need to rebuild your categories - see the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts

Comment: Thank morganfree. Using min/max is what I need for now. Rebuild categories is work but too complicate when I have a lot of series with different types (column, errorbar, scatter).