# Disabled points not hide. [Highcharts]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

nice to meet you.
I have a problem with my Chart.

I have a DB with some hiring process data. The process have many status: "ENDED","WORKING","STANDBY","CANCELLED". The process only have once at time.

I needed to use Stacked Column because if used normal one it let me tiny bars.

I have got all I wanted, but when I click in legend, the data category remains if there are not in the extremes.

[Here the gif showing what I mean](https://i.imgur.com/P8yo6jG.gifv)

And here's the code:

```
 var ch = Highcharts.chart('barChartContainer', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled:false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Detalles'
    },

    xAxis:{
      type: "category"
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Tiempo (dias)'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px"></span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{point.color};padding:0">Tiempo: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y} dias</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: "normal",
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0,
            events: {
                      legendItemClick: function () {
                          return this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                        }
                      }}}

    });

  var seriesArray = [];
<?php
$sqlEstados = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT (estado) as nombre_estado from proceso order by nombre_estado");
while ($rowEstados = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlEstados)){
  ?> ch.addSeries({name:"<?php echo $rowEstados['nombre_estado']?>", color: "    <?php echo $rowEstados['nombre_estado'] == "FINALIZADO" ? '#00C851' : ($rowEstados['nombre_estado'] == "WORKING" ? '#ffbb33' : (($rowEstados['nombre_estado'] == "PARADO" ? '#ff4444' :  '#33b5e5'))); ?>"});
<?php
} //INFLANDO LAS SERIES 03/07/2017 -> QUEDA INFLAR LAS CATEGORIAS CON OTRA FUNCION QUE DEVUELVA [[nombre,valor]]
 $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT timestampdiff(DAY,fecha_creacion, IFNULL(fecha_cerrado,NOW())) as t_diff_dias, (SELECT MAX(timestampdiff(DAY,fecha_creacion, IFNULL(fecha_cerrado,NOW()))) from proceso where not (estado='FINALIZADO' and fecha_cerrado IS NULL) ) as max_dias, id_proceso, proceso,estado from proceso where not (estado='FINALIZADO' and fecha_cerrado IS NULL)  ORDER BY id_proceso desc");
while ($rowSQL = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
  $var;
  switch ($rowSQL['estado']) {
    case 'FINALIZADO':
      $var = 1;
      break;
    case 'WORKING':
      $var = 3;
      break;
    case 'PARADO':
      $var = 2;
      break;
    default:
      $var = 0;
      break;
  }
echo "ch.series[".$var."].addPoint([\"".$rowSQL['proceso']."\",".$rowSQL['t_diff_dias']."]);";
}
?>
```

Thank you in advice.

EDIT: Thank you, I try something different. But I appreciate your support

Answer (score 0):

remove event from column also stacking, 
it works by default.
if your series data is fine then there will be no problem

```
 series: [
            {
        name: 'A1',
     data: [0,2,0,58,3]
    }, 
            {
        name: 'A2',
     data: [0,22,0,42,0]
    }, 
            {
        name: 'A3',
     data: [0,2,0,11,0]
    }, 
]
```

this  have 5 data columns in x axis and 3 series .
just if you need to check, my chart code, ignore the extra code

```
var q=jQuery.noConflict();
q(function () {
   q('#container3').highcharts({

chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Staff  Stats '
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Done',
            'New',
            'Working',
            'Pending',
            'Calls',
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Stats '
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
         name: 'A1',
         data: [0,2,0,58,3]
        }, 
        {
         name: 'A2',
         data: [0,22,0,42,0]
        }, 
        {
         name: 'A3',
         data: [0,2,0,11,0]
        }, 
    ]
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but not exactly what I want. The series are received dynamically and there are no categories as well.
The series are "working","standby", etc... and the data receives the hiring process and the time it took in progress. But when I try to hide the series in the middle or not in the extremes of the chart, the "categories" remains

Comment: you don't need a special event to shiow hide columns or bars when click on legend, it should work by default.

Comment: I deleted it and have no change. Middle bars dissappear but the data names still in x Axis. 
And if I not put stacking, my bars turns in tiny ones

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/4/ from the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts ?

Comment: i think its because of your series, probably its not in right format, from your echo series , i thinks its like  "2","5"     numbers inside inverted commas, which can create a graph, but the other functionality needs numbers not charachters, just try it, or you can share your resulted series,