# Highcharts more than one series

Tags: highcharts, visualization, series

I have a simple json document :

```
 [ {
  "x" : "a",
  "y" : 2
}, {
  "x" : "b",
  "y" : 8
}, {
  "x" : "c",
  "y" : 4
}, {
  "x" : "d",
  "y" : 15
} ]
```

I want to visualize it using Highcharts having 4 series. I could success, however, the data appeared only as one series (see the next Figure).

[image]

Here is part of the code:

```
  var options = {
.
.
.
 series: [{ }]
};

.
.
.
var data = JSON.parse(json);

 var seriesData = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    seriesData.push([data[i].x, data[i].y]); 
    options.xAxis.categories.push( data[i].x ); 
}

  options.series[0].data = seriesData;
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

also updating the series

```
chart.series[0].update({ 
              type: type, 
            });
```

works fine.

using

```
 options.series.push({name: data[i].x, data: [data[i].x, data[i].y]});
```

creates 4 series but not appropriately visualized and also updating the series

```
chart.series[0].update({ 
          type: type, 
        });
```

doesn't work, therefore, I want to focus in the first mentioned method.

any hints?

**EDit**: code which partially works for me:

```
    var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'column'   //default

            },
            title: {
                text: ''
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: 'Count',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                }
            },

            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    enabled: true,
                    text: '',
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'normal'
                    }
                },
                categories: [],
                crosshair: true
            } ,

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    innerSize: 125,
                    depth: 80
                },
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                     grouping: false
                }  

            },   
             series: [{  }]
        };


// Set type
$.each(['column', 'pie'], function (i, type) {
    $('#' + type).click(function () { 


  chart.series[0].update({ 
                  type: type 
        }); 

 });



 var data = get the data fom json file**

 var seriesData = [];  
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    seriesData.push([data[i].x, data[i].y]); 
   options.xAxis.categories.push( data[i].x ); 


}

  options.series[0].data = seriesData;
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);  

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide whether you want to have 4 different series and update all 4 series at once or you want to have one series an then build e.g. legend on your own.

If you want to have 4 series, set grouping to false, set xAxis categories and each point should be mapped to one series with one point - the point.x should have the index of the series.

```
const series = data.map((point, x) => ({ name: point.x, data: [{ x, y: point.y }]}))

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: data.map(point => point.x)
  },
  series: series
});
```

Then you can update your all 4 series:

```
  chart.series.forEach(series => series.update({
    type: series.type === 'column' ? 'scatter' : 'column'
  }, false))

  chart.redraw()
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pdjqrj5y/

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am running the script under some special platform which your code doesn't run under it. I have uploaded the same library you have but with no success. I updated my question with the code which works for me. Maybe you can check and tell me how I can have 4 series for column type. For pie it works fine.

Comment: You can use babel transpiler to transpile the code to older version of ES which will run in older environment - paste the code here https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Thanks a lot now it works. However, when I used "pie" as type I just see the serious not (only one color with "slice" label). In my code actually "pie", "area" etc. works fine.  Any hints

Comment: To build a pie you need only one series - so you need to map 4 series column to a single series pie - e.g. like this http://jsfiddle.net/pdjqrj5y/1/

Comment: there is small bug, when you click on any columns between first and last one the chart is not drawing correctly where the clicked column disappear and its x label stay and hence you see empty space between columns.

Comment: Then you are looking for hiding/showing category functionality - you can see how you can implement this in this topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956134/how-to-hide-show-a-column-in-a-basic-column-graph-of-highcharts